# Is there a term before the first term in a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was skimming through some questions on arithmetic sequences and I came across one that confused me it goes:
 The sum of three consecutive terms of an A.P. is 18 and their product 120. Find the terms.
The terms they used were (a-d), a, (a+d). If a is the first term then what term is (a-d) and why was it used.

Comment: In this case, $a$ is the second term.

Comment: More precisely, $a$ is the second term among three consecutive terms. So for example, $a$ can be the twelfth term of the whole sequence, $a-d$ the eleventh and $a+d$ the thirteenth

Answer (score 2):

Call the three elements in arithmetic progression Good, Bad and Ugly. Then the assumptions are that

1. There exists $d$ such that $\mathit{Bad}=\mathit{Good}+d$ and $\mathit{Ugly}=\mathit{Bad}+d$;
2. $\mathit{Good}+\mathit{Bad}+\mathit{Ugly}=18$;
3. $\mathit{Good}\cdot\mathit{Bad}\cdot\mathit{Ugly}=120$.

Well, maybe using $G=\mathit{Good}$, $B=\mathit{Bad}$ and $U=\mathit{Ugly}$ might make things simpler. Then the second and third conditions would become
$$
G+(G+d)+(G+2d)=18,\qquad G(G+d)(G+2d)=120
$$
However, exploiting symmetry is always better. Note that if we change $d$ to $-d$, we get another feasible solution *with the same middle term*.

Thus, instead of starting from the first term, we start from the second:
$$
(B-d)+B+(B+d)=18,\qquad (B-d)B(B+d)=120
$$
Isn't this simpler? The first equation becomes $3B=18$, so $B=6$. Therefore the second equation is
$$
6(6-d)(6+d)=120
$$
or $36-d^2=20$, thus $d^2=16$ and $d=\pm4$.

If $d=4$, we have $\mathit{Good}=6-4=2$, $\mathit{Bad}=6$, $\mathit{Ugly}=6+4=10$; if $d=-4$, we have $\mathit{Good}=6+4=10$, $\mathit{Bad}=6$, $\mathit{Ugly}=6-4=2$.

“Bad” was not so bad, after all!

Answer (score 0):

Well $a$ is not the first term of that A.P., instead it is the second term. In fact the first term of that A.P. is $a-d$. It can be made easier to visualize by setting $a-d=b$ and so you get $a=b+d$ and $a+d=b+2d$. So nevertheless, they are considering the A.P. $b,b+d,b+2d$ with $b=a-d$. Such type of substitutions are made especially when the problem refers to product of terms because in that case we can use the identity $(a+d)(a-d)=a^2-d^2$ which makes the product look better. Also sometimes such substitutions are made in the case of adding terms in an A.P. because $(a+d)+(a)+(a-d)=3a$ looks much better than $(b)+(b+d)+(b+2d)=3b+3d$.